# How to show domain name in the browser URL instead of the IP address of the hosted machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jakarta-ee, amazon-ec2, web-deployment, domain-name

I'm a high school student. I recently developed a Java web application and deployed in AWS. I also bought a domain from 1and1. I also configured in 1and1 to redirect web request to my web app in AWS. But how do I set the URL of my application to the domain name? Now it's showing the IP address. Please pardon me for any mistake in my question, this is my first application and I learned all this myself. Thanks.

If needed these are the techs I mostly used

- Spring Boot
- MongoDB
- ActiveMQ

Comment: In general these questions would be down voted and closed, but just because you are high school student and to encourage someone like you, I upvoted and one of the way is use Route53 (assuming your DNS provider is Amazon). http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-configuring.html

Comment: My DNS provider is 1and1

Comment: "But I want the URL of my web app in AWS to show my domain name instead of IP address" not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: Thanks Kosa for your support. My Current URL in AWS is like this "http://192.12.121.0....."........... I want to change this to my domain, like "www.abc.com".

Comment: You can't change it and you don't need to. If you DNS routing configurations done properly on 1and1, you should be able to access your application by using URL instead of IP. DNS is where you configure url to IP mapping, you don't really replace IP of box for this to work.

Comment: I'm able to access my web app both via IP address and domain name. But in both the cases URL shown in the browser is my IP address not the domain name.

Comment: What is your server?Is it tomcat?

Comment: Yes. I'm using apache tomcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps

1. Locate the httpd-vhosts.conf file.(should be inside your conf\extra folder of the server home)
2. Add the following, at the bottom of the file, new virtual hosts for
   each domain.

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerName www.abc.com
>     ServerAlias abc.com
>     DocumentRoot......./htdocs/myapp
>    </VirtualHost>
> ```

Save the file and restart the server